# SP2010 - Formatted data view web part saved to gallery - get error when dropped on parent site

Tags: web-part, formatting

I have a list on a subsite that I need to feature on the parent site homepage. I created the formatted data view and saved it as a web part in the gallery. I drop it on the homepage but get a "web part cannot be displayed, troubleshoot in designer" error message.

Then I created an unformatted data view and saved it to the gallery. I was able to get it to appear on the parent site homepage, but when I tried to apply conditional formatting - the columns for the "apply formatting" window don't appear -  As in "Column"  . It's all blank.

Am I missing something? It's just a simple dashboard with three traffic light indicators.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what I think it is, you need to export the web part to its Xml format (either .dwp or .webpart) and then edit it to fill in the WebID with the ID of the web that contains the list itself.  Once that is done, you should be able to upload that as a webpart on any page in the site collection and it would work as expected.

You might also have to do something with the list ID or list url in the Xml, but I'm not certain on that.